# Trying to call a function within class to perform a multiplication

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
class Compagnie:
    def __init__(self, nom, actions, prix):
        self.nom = nom
        self.actions = actions
        self.prix = prix

    def set_nom(self):
        print("Changer le nom de la compagnie pour " + self.nom)

    def setActions(self):
        print("Changer le nombre d'actions pour " + self.actions)

    def setPrix(self):
        print("Changer le prix de l'action pour " + self.prix)

    def get_prix_compagnie(self):
        valeur = self.action * self.prix
        print("La compagnie vaut : " + valeur)
```

When I run :

```
Compagnie = Compagnie("Compagnie", "5460", "500")
Compagnie.setActions()
```

Everything works. It prints the new "actions" value.

But i'm having problems with the `get_prix_compagnie` function. This function is supposed to multiply the action and the prix and return a number.

I tried `self.action * self.prix` but it's not working, giving me this error : `AttributeError: 'Compagnie' object has no attribute 'action'`

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: i'm sorry sir !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont't you mean `actions`?

```
valeur = str(int(self.actions) * int(self.prix))
```

Comment: yes indeed. sorry. Now I got this error : TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: I edited the answer. @JessicaZveknia

Comment: Thank you! but now I got this error : TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: I got the whole picture, see the edit. @JessicaZveknia

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much.... can you explain to me why it happened?

Comment: First error was due to the fact that the arguments were input as string, so I converted them to int. In the second line, you try to print by concatenating with `+` which requires all operands as string. If you don't want to convert the int, you can do `print("La compagnie vaut : ", valeur)`. @JessicaZveknia